# Issue with mac'os Catalina and parallels

Tags: windows-10, macos, parallels, macos-catalina

I'm running Parallels VM version 13.3.0 on my mac and ever since I upgraded my mac'os to Catalina, Windows 10 is running very slow on the VM (It just looks very laggy).
My mac is running normally good, the activity monitor and task manager looks good as well.

Does someone know what can be the issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Parallels 13 isn't supported on Catalina - you need v15

Ref Parallels KB - [Known issues with macOS 10.15 Catalina and Parallels Desktop for Mac](https://kb.parallels.com/124705)